# How to get mean value by function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I need to get basic statistics values, such as `mean()`, `var()`, `std()` from   some columns in different dataframes.

I want to do it by creating a function, and then apply it to my dataframes. I am trying to do it in two ways: crate a function for column and for dataframe.

```py
def stat (column):
    mu=column.mean()
    return mu

data['column'].apply(stat)

def stat (dataframe):
    mu=dataframe['column'].mean()
    return mu

data.apply(stat,axis=1)
```

In both cases I get the error AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'mean'", 'occurred at index 0')
How can I build such function to get values I need? I will be thankfull for any help.

Comment: You can use in-built functions in pandas `df['column'].mean()`  directly. It seems to be much shorter than `data['column'].apply(stat)`

Comment: Yes, I can, but I want to get mean(), var(), std() from more than 20 columns in different dataframes. And I want to automatize a bit  this process. If it is possible, off course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in functions directly on your dataframe:

```py
>> data = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 5.0]], columns=['column', 'column2'])
>> data
   column  column2
0     1.0      2.0
1     4.0      5.0

>> data['column'].mean()
2.5

>> data[['column', 'column2']].mean()
column     2.5
column2    3.5
dtype: float64

# Multiple methods:
>> data[['column', 'column2']].aggregate(['mean', 'std', 'var'])
       column  column2
mean  2.50000  3.50000
std   2.12132  2.12132
var   4.50000  4.50000
```

Your errors comes from your attempt of trying to take the mean of a single individual float value, which is not possible. You can see that you are trying to take the mean of a single value by executing the following:

```py
>> data['column'].apply(print)
1.0  # your function tries to apply mean to this value
4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Off course I didn't think, than function handles to only one value... I'm noob...

Comment: No problem. If this answer was sufficient for your problem, then please accept it so that your question is closed :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in function `DataFrame.describe()` to generate metrics such as mean, std, and quantiles for all columns of dataframe

Answer (score 0):

As SH-SF said in his comment, And as Bob said in the answer you can just use `df['column'].mean()` to get the mean value of a column. Note in here that `df['column']` is a pandas Series. You can also get the mean for several or all columns of a dataframe by using `df.mean()` which will give the mean value for each column of the dataframe. Now you can also use `df.mean(axis=1)` to get the 'horizontal mean' that is the mean value for each row. Of course all values need to be of numeric type, and it needs to...make sense if you see what I mean.